# Where is ragel's source repository

Tags: ragel

The original address no longer working git://git.complang.org/ragel.git.
Google search only shows unofficial repository from the old code.

Since its development is under Colm Network now, would Colm Networks still open its development repository?

Comment: Who owns what under what policy is a business question, not a programming question.

Comment: Business question about project ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Colm web site:

> Since we cannot operate in the open, the git repository for Ragel  will no longer be available. The project will be published as release (and pre-release) tarballs only. On the upside, Ragel will get much more attention.
>
> The license will remain the same: GPLv2 with an exception for the generated code derived from Ragel source.

Comment: I missed the news detail.

Comment: This really sucks. I wonder if there is an open-source fork (which accepts patches) with traction?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to have the source on hand for reference, you can get it with:

```
$ curl https://www.colm.net/files/ragel/ragel-6.9.tar.gz | tar -xz
```

There is a list of available versions [here](https://www.colm.net/files/ragel).